# Can a class be annotated as both @Repository and @Entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am pretty new to Hibernate. I am having problem understanding these simple logics. I have understood that @Repository is used by Spring for accessing objects. Also, Hibernate uses @Entity to denote entities which are mapped into database tables. I was just wondering if a single class can be annotated with both @Repository and @Entity as they more or less imply the same.

Comment: NO (this is for min comment length)

Comment: Sounds like ActiveRecord ;)

Comment: Sounds like a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - I guess its popular with Ruby because it has mix-ins and duck-typing, so its not really cluttering the entity interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO.

Hibernate entities are managed by Hibernate ORM framework, they(and their proxies) are created by hibernate when you access them via get() or load(). They have a completely different (and complex) lifecycle than the Spring beans(they can be attached/detached/proxied/pending for removal)

Spring repositories are singletons, managed by Spring framework. Typically they exist as long as the container instance exists. New Hibernate sessions may be opened and closed, new user sessions engaged and then expired, but there still will be the same singleton instances of repositories.

Please see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview for the possible hibernate object states.

As for the repository instances - typically they are stateless, as they are services.

RE: `they more or less imply the same.` No they are not the same. There was [an old joke](http://www.anvari.org/shortjoke/Computer_Light_Bulb_Jokes/26_how-many-c-programmers-does-it-take-to-change-a-light-bulb.html)

> How many C++ programmers does it take to change a light bulb? You're
>   still thinking procedurally. A properly designed light bulb object
>   would inherit a change method from a generic light bulb class, so all
>   you would have to do is send a light-bulb-change message.

But good OOP programmers do not think that way, according to [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) objects should should have a single reason to change. Repository works with the infrastructure and has nothing to do with the business rules. Infrastructure may change(you may need for example to store you object in XML instead of RDBMS), but this should not affect the classes encapsulating the state of business objects.

You can possibly mitigate this problem by making a reference from the entity class to an abstract repository interface(implement an infamous [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern - it will be like referencing some abstract bulb socket from the bulb, this does not seem to be a good solution because bulb sockets and bulbs have different lifecycles).

That is where [High Cohesion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc947917.aspx) principle  starts to play, according to which it's just illogical for an object, whose role is to reflect the abstractions from the model, to perform some completely unrelated things like persistence or transmitting over the network. It's weird when `Student` class will have `print()`, `saveToXml()` or `transmitByHttp()` methods.

Answer (score 5):

They don't imply the same thing at all.

***@Entity***

An @Entity is something that represents a "thing" in your business domain. It could be anything - a Customer, an Elephant, a Product. . . It will have attributes that will get persisted to the database as well as methods relating to those attributes (at least it should, unless it's an anaemic entity, but that's an anti-pattern. . . . later, when you're comfortable with the basics check out Spring's @Configurable annotation - this allows you to provide collaborators to your entity).

***@Repository***

A @Repository, on the other hand provides an interface for retrieving and storing those entities.

There are some frameworks, especially in other languages, that combine the persistence and entity attributes on the same object, however this is not common in Java/Hibernate/Spring.

Comment: The other answer has lots of good info,  but this is more concise and to the point, so it gets my vote.